# Conditional formatting on all cells that have font size 21?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I apply conditional formatting to all cells which have their font size set to 21?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your input and output situations from `How do I apply conditional formatting to all cells which have their font size set to 21?`. Can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: I have 4 cells. two with size 13 font, and two with size 21 font. I want to apply conditional formatting to the entire sheet that will only affect the cells that have size 21 font.

Comment: I imagine I will have to use a custom formula that will check the font size - but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Better to let go of conditional formatting and use the script alone to getfont size and set format

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of what [@TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster) proposed:

```js
function fontSizeBackgroundColor() {
  const sS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  const dataR = sS.getDataRange()
  for (let i = 1; i <= dataR.getLastColumn(); i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j <= dataR.getLastRow(); j++) {
      const r = sS.getRange(i, j)
      const fS = r.getFontSize()
      if (fS >= 21) {
        r.setBackground("blue")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you read [Best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)? Looping over the range is slow.  Better to always use arrays. In this case,  using `getFontSizes()` and looping over is significantly faster than `getFontSize()` for each `range`.

Comment: I read it and understand it, thanks, but this is not "The best way to approach" is just a quick way to do it. You can share your version using the best practices, that will be awesome.

Comment: Thank you both Emel and TheMaster. Very helpful!